# Image in button is blurry, button ignores setSize

Tags: java, android, button, android-studio

I have two problems with creating buttons in android application.

1. Image in button (classic `Button`) is blurry. I think Android studio increase size of image, but not sure with it. Here is screen from emulator and used image: [image: screen from emulator]
   [image: used icon]

Is here a way how I can remove this blurry effect?

2. During creating buttons, I set height of button, but it looks like button ignores this when it have icon inside (even `maxSize`). 
   How can I set size of button?

This is code with creating buttons.

```
       LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        Button button;
        for(Subreddit s:subreddits)
        {
            button = new Button(this);

            Drawable img = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.reddit2);
            //img.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 60);
            button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(img, null, null, null);

            button.setMinHeight(0);
            button.setHeight(30);
            button.setText(s.getDisplayName());
            button.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_shape2));
            button.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.button_text_color));
            button.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            button.setAllCaps(false);
            button.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);
            button.setMaxHeight(35);

            layout.addView(button);
        }
        layout.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) with *setImageResource*.
 Also,i would use a RecyclerView ora ListView and not build it like that.
 There is no need to call invalidate, once u add a view to the viewgroup it already calls invalidate. invalidate is a costly method.